# Database systems concept question number 3.6

Tags: sql

Consider the sql query

```
Select p.a1
From p,r1,r2
Where p.a1 = r1.a1 or p.a1 = r2.a1
```

Under what conditions does the preceding query select values of p.a1 
that are either in r1 or in r2?Examine carefully the cases where one of 
r1 or r2 may be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "In all cases where p.a1 is not null"